# Looking for a motorcycle database

Tags: transportation, database, open-source

I've been looking for a while for a database (or API) containing information about motorcycles. Notament :

- Brand
- Model
- Year of manufacture
- If possible various technical information
- And also if possible the different maintenance to be done on the vehicle.

The best would be a free base (because it is, for the moment, for a personal project). But why not later on move to a paid base but with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bikes Price and Specs](https://www.kaggle.com/mohanraj7/bikes-specifications)

The dataset containing bike manufacturer, model, price and other specifications

---

[Vehicle dataset from cardekho](https://www.kaggle.com/nehalbirla/vehicle-dataset-from-cardekho)

Used Cars and motorcycles data

---

**Additional Resources**

- http://pages.ebay.com/motors/compatibility/download.html

Need to web scrap

- https://www.autoevolution.com/moto/
- https://bikez.com/main/index.php

---

**Paid:**

[Teoalida's Car Database](https://www.teoalida.com/cardatabase/motorcycles/)
The most updated automobile database – Excel, CSV, SQL files for download

Answer (score 0):

Here is a motorcycle specs database API, on the RapidApi marketplace:
https://rapidapi.com/makingdatameaningful/api/motorcycle-specs-database

Answer (score 0):

There's a scraped version of bikez.com now:

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/emmanuelfwerr/motorcycle-technical-specifications-19702022

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).